# Anomaly detection using Bayesian networks

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on the problem of anomaly detection in multivariate time series data using Bayesian networks.

I am confused is it a good approach to use the dynamic Bayesian network model for anomaly detection? As using Bayesian approach one can only calculate the probability of occurrence of similarity of data on trained data.

Is there is any other approach to solve the same using other outlier score method?

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

'similar to trained data' would be considered as 'Normal' then,

1 - (probability of occurrence of similarity of data on trained data)

would be your *anomaly score/probability*. You can use many different methods for anomaly detection with simple anomaly score calculation design.

examples of [uni-variable time series anomaly detection](http://manmustbecool.github.io/MyWiki/papers/A%20Streaming%20Data%20Anomaly%20Detection%20Analytic%20Engine%20for%20Mobile%20Network%20Management.pdf)